"pagetracker" option not working with "verbose-trad2" citestyle
Compiling with biber, I need to reset the page tracker on each page to avoid an "Ibid." at the beginning of a new page. With the citestyle authortitle-icomp, for instance, it works fine.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authortitle-icomp,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    pagetracker=page,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[hidelinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{RotVerdalleCinema,
    address = {Paris},
    editor = {Gwenaële Rot and Laure {de Verdalle}},
    pagetotal = {240},
    publisher = {La Dispute},
    subtitle = {Travail et organisation},
    title = {Le Cinéma},
    year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\clearpage

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\end{document}


But I need to use the verbose-trad2 citestyle, which, unfortunately, breaks the option:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=verbose-trad2,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    pagetracker=page,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[hidelinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{RotVerdalleCinema,
    address = {Paris},
    editor = {Gwenaële Rot and Laure {de Verdalle}},
    pagetotal = {240},
    publisher = {La Dispute},
    subtitle = {Travail et organisation},
    title = {Le Cinéma},
    year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\clearpage

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\end{document}


I have noticed that none of the verbose-trad styles make this work. Would it be possible to have it working with this citestyle?

By default the verbose-trad... styles do not check if a citation is the first on a new page. We can add that in by changing the test \ifciteibid in the cite bibmacro to the more complex test \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteibid} and not test {\iffirstonpage}}. If we just change that, then you will get an "idem" citation instead, which is probably equally undesirable, so we need to add a and not test {\iffirstonpage} there as well.
We end up with
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=verbose-trad2,
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  pagetracker=page,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[hidelinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteibid} and not test {\iffirstonpage}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteidem} and not bool {cbx:noidem}
                         and not test {\iffirstonpage}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{RotVerdalleCinema,
    address = {Paris},
    editor = {Gwenaële Rot and Laure {de Verdalle}},
    pagetotal = {240},
    publisher = {La Dispute},
    subtitle = {Travail et organisation},
    title = {Le Cinéma},
    year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\clearpage

First note\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema} and second one\footcite{RotVerdalleCinema}.
\end{document}



Perfect answer, thanks a lot!
